# Combinar tuplas o consultas mysql con python

Tags: python

Tengo en el momento dos querys que se ejecutan en bases de arquitectura diferentes, estos me arrojan diferentes datos, teniendo en común el primer valor, lo que quiero hacer es que de mi primer consulta en la posición [0] buscar en todas las listas del segundo query en la posición [0], cuando coincidan traer determinadas posiciones y en caso de no encontrar nada rellenarlo de ''.

Estos son los datos:

Query 1

```py
for row in query1:
        print(row)
```

```
('MP220004561165', '0523', '628', 'N', 1008, 0, 'N')
('MP220005432952', '0511', '0', 'S', 1008, 0, 'S')
('MP220007767225', '0509', '645', 'S', 1008,  0, 'N')
('MP220007864896', '0052', '792', 'S', 1008,  0, 'N')
('MP220007992814', '0436', '0', 'S', 1008, 0, 'N')
```

Query 2

```py
for row in query2:
        print(row)
```

```
('MP220004561165', 'BBB', 0, 0, 3, 998, 30, 'SO', '0523', 'SOLICITANTE', 3)
('MP220005432952', 'AAA', 12, 12, 998, 144, 'CA', '0511', 'SOLICITANTE', 1)
```

Lo que se espero:

```py
for row in query1:
        print(row)
```

```
('MP220004561165', '0523', '628', 'N', 1008, 0, 'N','BBB',998,'SOLICITANTE',3)
('MP220007767225', '0509', '645', 'S', 1008,  0, 'N','','', '', '')
('MP220005432952', '0511', '0', 'S', 1008, 0, 'S','AAA','0511', 'SOLICITANTE', 1)
('MP220007864896', '0052', '792', 'S', 1008,  0, 'N','','', '', '')
('MP220007992814', '0436', '0', 'S', 1008, 0, 'N','','', '', '')
```

Este es mi código:

```
def Base_adherencia():
    print("Iniciando Base_adherencia")
    apro = {}
    for row in pcorte: ##pcorte es el resultado de la consulta 
        apro[row[0]] = row
##    print(apro)
        
    val = Validaciones() ##Validaciones es el resultado de la consulta 
    qval = {}

    for row in val:
        qval[row[0]]=row
##    print(qval)
        
    res = []

    for key, apro_row in apro.items():
        qval_row = qval[key] if key in qval else {1:'',5:'',9:'',10:''}
        res.append(apro_row + [qval_row[1], qval_row[5], qval_row[9], qval_row[10]])
    print(res)
```

Comment: No sería mejor unir ambas consultas usando un [left join](https://programacionymas.com/blog/como-funciona-inner-left-right-full-join#:~:text=Clerical-,Cl%C3%A1usula%20LEFT%20JOIN,-A%20diferencia%20de)? Podrías agregar los querys para ver si se pueden unir? Digo todo esto por que mysql es más rapido y claro que Python para ese tipo de procedimientos.

Comment: Buen día, no es muy claro lo que quieres hacer, teniendo el primer índice de la primera consulta `('MP220004561165', '0523', '628', 'N', 1008, 0, 'N')` y el primer índice de la segunda consulta `('MP220004561165', 'BBB', 0, 0, 3, 998, 30, 'SO', '0523', 'SOLICITANTE', 3)`, ¿Cómo se llegó a esto? `('MP220004561165', '0523', '628', 'N', 1008, 0, 'N','BBB',998,'SOLICITANTE',3)`. En el enunciado dices que cada elemento de la primera consulta se busca en la segunda consulta, pero ¿Por qué algunos valores de la segunda se ignoran?

Comment: ('MP220004561165', '0523', '628', 'N', 1008, 0, 'N','BBB',998,'SOLICITANTE',3) es el resultado al que quiero llegar, no quiero todos los datos  de la segunda solo unas posiciones cuando coincida.

Comment: No es tan complicado de resolver, pero hay una importante inconsistencia en los datos lo cual crea una ambigüedad. En el dataset de **Query 2**, el primer registro tiene `11 elementos` y el segundo `10`. ¿Cómo saber cuál registro falta si es una lista plana? ¿Es un **typo** (más probable), o el SQL devolvió una lista truncada?. Aclarar o corregir eso. Si el resultado de la consulta viene de forma dispar, sugiero entonces usar la forma asociativa `"clave":"valor"`.

Comment: @aeportugal no entiendo muy bien tu pregunta, segun entiendo tu consulota es porqué al final tiene 11 posiciones, eso es por que le quiero añadir algunas del query 2, o si hay que crear uno nuevo no habria lío, ya que en si quiero es unir el query1 con algunos datos del query2 , cuando coincidan., es eso?

Comment: No. La pregunta es: ¿por qué en el resultado del Query 2 la primera fila tiene **11** elementos y la segunda tiene **10**? No creo que el SQL te devuelva filas con distinta cantidad de elementos. Si falta uno al menos debería devolver vacío, `''`, o `NULL`.

Comment: @aeportugal era en el ultimo registro?, ya elimine una ", " que estaba de más

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que tienes un typo en el segundo dataset query 2 (ver mi comentario en la pregunta) y que todas sus filas tienen igual cantidad de datos (**11**), se puede hacer lo que solicitas de forma más simple si cambias `apro` y `val` a diccionarios, así buscar una llave de un diccionario en el otro es mucho más fácil:

```py
apro = {}
for row in query2:
    apro[row[0]] = row

val = {}
for row in query1:
    val[row[0]] = row
```

Tanto `apro` como `val` serán diccionarios de esta forma:

```
{
    'MP220004561165' : ['MP220004561165', '0523', '628', ...], 
    'MP220005432952' : ['MP220005432952', '0511', '0', ...], 
    ...
}
```

Ahora  solo hay que recorrer `apro` (`llave:valor`), y por cada llave de `apro` que se encuentre en `val`, entonces agregar los elementos requeridos. Si la llave no se encuentra, rellenar con espacios:

```py
res = []
for key, apro_row in apro.items():
    val_row = val[key] if key in val else {1:'', 5:'', 9:'', 10:''}
    res.append(apro_row + [val_row[1], val_row[5], val_row[9], val_row[10]])
```

El resultado es, pues, la variable `res`.

Comment: Dale, muchas gracias , ya mismo lo voy a probar, gracias

Comment: @arportuga , consulta, por qué al comento de concatenarlo me lo detecta como tupla , aun cuando lo pase a diccionario, tal como lo indicaste, hice la prueba de imprimir cada diccionario y los imprime en ese formato, pero al hacer el res.apped me da error de tupla      res.append(apro_row + [qval_row[1], qval_row[5], qval_row[9], qval_row[10]])
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple

Answer (score 0):

Viendo que no es posible usar left join ya que son bases de datos distintas, recomiendo usar Pandas para relacionar los datos de ambas bases.

Pros de usar Pandas:

- Es más rapido que Python puro debido a que sus funciones y métodos están implementados en c.
- El código es más legible

Contras de Pandas

- No viene en la librería estandar, por lo que hay que instalarlo.

---

Para lograr lo que buscas usando Pandas (que sería un left join), luego de cargar el contenido devuelto por ambas bases en DataFrames (por ejemplo `pandas.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall(), ...)`), es usar [pandas.DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) con how="left", que es lo más parecido al left join que hay en Pandas.

Nota: yo usaré el parametro on, pero si las columnas de ambos DataFrames no se llaman igual, tendrás que recurrir en su lugar a los parametros left_on y right_on.

Luego puedes reemplazar todos los NaN resultantes de merge por una cadena vacía usando [pandas.DataFrame.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).

Puesto en practica:

```
import pandas as pd

query1 = pd.DataFrame([('MP220004561165', '0523', '628', 'N', 1008, 0, 'N'),
                       ('MP220005432952', '0511', '0', 'S', 1008, 0, 'S'),
                       ('MP220007767225', '0509', '645', 'S', 1008,  0, 'N'),
                       ('MP220007864896', '0052', '792', 'S', 1008,  0, 'N'),
                       ('MP220007992814', '0436', '0', 'S', 1008, 0, 'N')])

query2 = pd.DataFrame([('MP220004561165', 'BBB', 0, 0, 3, 998, 30, 'SO', '0523', 'SOLICITANTE', 3),
                       ('MP220005432952', 'AAA', 12, 12, 998, 144, 'CA', '0511', 'SOLICITANTE', 1)])

df = query1.merge(query2, how="left", on=0)
df = df.fillna('')

print(df)
```

Produce:

```
                0   1_x  2_x 3_x   4_x  ...  6_y     7            8            9   10
0  MP220004561165  0523  628   N  1008  ...   30    SO         0523  SOLICITANTE  3.0
1  MP220005432952  0511    0   S  1008  ...   CA  0511  SOLICITANTE            1     
2  MP220007767225  0509  645   S  1008  ...                                          
3  MP220007864896  0052  792   S  1008  ...                                          
4  MP220007992814  0436    0   S  1008  ...                                          

[5 rows x 17 columns]
```